# Drawn circle appearing twice in my table view cells in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell

In my tableview cell, I draw a circle that represents the percentage of correct answers, but I don't know why, this circle appears twice only on some device (iPhone SE 1st gen or iPhone 12 Pro max for example).

I don't think that this is coming from the reusable cell because it is coming directly without any scrolling.

Note that I used same method to drawn same circle on another place in the app, it is working perfectly.

I searched deeply in my code, I am calling this method only once for the cell, so I came to the conclusion that this is a bug... I am a bit lost here, I feel my code is Ok, so I guess I am more looking for a tip to get rid of this second circle.

**Class for my percentage circle methods :**

```
class PercentageCircle{
// Pattern singleton
public static let percentageCircle = PercentageCircle()



// Public init for pattern singleton
public init() {}

// Method to create and animate percentage circle
func createPercentageCircle(percentage: Int,
                            circleRadius: CGFloat,
                            circleXPosition: CGFloat,
                            circleYPosition: CGFloat,
                            circleWidth: CGFloat,
                            circleColor: CGColor,
                            backgroundColor: CGColor,
                            animation: Bool) -> UIView? {
    
    // Percentage circle to be animated
    let percentageCircle = CAShapeLayer()
    
    // Add a view
    let roundView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: circleXPosition, y: circleYPosition, width: circleRadius, height: circleRadius))
    
    // Start of the arc corresponds to 12 0'clock
    let startAngle = -CGFloat.pi / 2
    // Proportion depending of percentage
    let proportion = CGFloat(percentage)
    let centre = CGPoint (x: roundView.frame.size.width / 2, y: roundView.frame.size.height / 2)
    let radius = roundView.frame.size.width / 2
    // The proportion of a full circle
    let arc = CGFloat.pi * 2 * proportion / 100
    
    // Add the background circle
    let backgroundCircle = CAShapeLayer()
    // Add path for background circle
    let pathBackground = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centre, radius: radius, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi , clockwise: true)
    // Attributes of the background circle
    backgroundCircle.strokeColor = backgroundColor
    backgroundCircle.lineWidth = circleWidth * 1.7
    // Put transparency to the center of the circles
    backgroundCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    // Atribute the path
    backgroundCircle.path = pathBackground.cgPath
    
    // Add the circle to the view
    roundView.layer.addSublayer(backgroundCircle)
    
    // Add the path of the percentage circle
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centre, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: startAngle  + arc, clockwise: true)
    
    // Attribute the path to the percentage circle
    percentageCircle.path = circularPath.cgPath
    
    // Attributes of the percentage circle
    percentageCircle.strokeColor = circleColor
    percentageCircle.lineWidth = circleWidth
    percentageCircle.lineCap = .round
    percentageCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    
    // Check if animation is true
    if animation {
        // Do not draw the circle
        percentageCircle.strokeEnd = 0.0
        // Draw the circle thru the animation
        animateCircle(percentageCircle: percentageCircle)
        // Add the circle to the the view
        roundView.layer.addSublayer(percentageCircle)
    } else {
        // Draw the circle
        percentageCircle.strokeEnd = 1.0
        // Add the circle to the the view
        roundView.layer.addSublayer(percentageCircle)
    }
    
    return roundView
}

// Method to animate the circle
private func animateCircle(percentageCircle: CAShapeLayer) {
    let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    // Set the animation to the total value
    basicAnimation.toValue = 1
    // Set the time of the animation
    basicAnimation.duration = 1
    // Set the circle to stay once the animation is completed
    basicAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
    basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    
    // Add the animation to the percentage circle
    percentageCircle.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "keyAnimation")
}
```

}

**Code for my cell**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailStatsCell", for: indexPath) as? StatsTableViewCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
        }
    
    let kanjiCurrentKey = kanjiStatArray[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.kanjiLabel.text = kanjiStatArray[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.appearnceLabel.text = "Appearance : \(Stats.stats.countKanjiQuizz[kanjiCurrentKey] ?? 0)"
    

    if let statCorrect = Stats.stats.countKanjiCorrect[kanjiCurrentKey] {
        // Calculate the percentage
        let percentageKanjiCell = Int(100 * Double(statCorrect) / Double(Stats.stats.countKanjiQuizz[kanjiCurrentKey] ?? 1))

        // Set the correct answers if more than 1
        cell.correctLabel.text = "Correct : \(statCorrect)"

        // Set the correct percentage
        cell.percentageLabel.text = String(percentageKanjiCell) + " %"

        // Draw the circle with the percentage in it
        drawCircle(percentage: percentageKanjiCell, cell: cell)
    } else {
        // Set the correct answers to 0 and draw the circle at 0%
        cell.correctLabel.text = "Correct : 0"
        drawCircle(percentage: 0, cell: cell)
    }
    
    
    return cell
}

//MARK: Draw percentage circle with percentage label
private func drawCircle(percentage: Int, cell: StatsTableViewCell){
    // Calculate the circle radius
    var circleRadius: CGFloat {
        return cell.frame.height/2 + 10
    }
    
    // Calculate the x position of the percentage circle
    var circleXPosition: CGFloat {
        return cell.frame.width - (circleRadius) - 10
    }
    
    // Calculate the y position of the percentage circle
    var circleYPosition: CGFloat {
        return cell.frame.height/2 - (circleRadius/2)
    }
    


    // Call method from PercentageCircle class

    roundView = PercentageCircle.percentageCircle.createPercentageCircle(percentage: percentage, circleRadius: circleRadius, circleXPosition: circleXPosition, circleYPosition: circleYPosition, circleWidth: 5, circleColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.276517272, green: 0.2243287563, blue: 0.4410637617, alpha: 1), backgroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1), animation: false)
    
    cell.addSubview(roundView)
}
```

**This is how it is supposed to be (iPhone 12 mini)**

[image]

**This is how it looks on some devices (iPhone 12 Pro max)**

[image]

Comment: Cells are reused when tableviews scroll. On smaller devices a scroll is more likely.  You add a subview each time`cellForRow` is called. Don't do that.  Create the circle view once when the cell is created and simply update its value in `cellForRow`

Comment: Thanks a lot Paulw11 !! I change the method location like you suggested and called it in the "override func prepareForReuse()" from the cell itself, it is perfect !!